# Difference between SomeClass<T extends OtherClass> and SomeClass<T super OtherClass>

Tags: java, generics

What's the difference between:

```
SomeClass<T extends OtherClass>
```

and

```
SomeClass<T super OtherClass>
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910892/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-extends-in-java-generics

Comment: there is no `SomeClass<T super OtherClass>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sun says (from [Using and Programming Generics in J2SE 5.0](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/generics/))

> There are three types of wildcards:
>
> 1. "? extends Type": Denotes a family of subtypes of type Type. This is the most useful wildcard
> 2. "? super Type": Denotes a family of supertypes of type Type
> 3. "?": Denotes the set of all types or any

[More Fun with Wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html) gives some good examples to all three types.

---

Another good example (taken from the video recommended by @Adrian) is:

```
class Stack<E> {
    void pushAll( Collection<? extends E> src );
    void popAll( Collection<? super E> dest );
}
```

Here you can see the difference between `super` and `extends`:

For the method `pushAll` imagine you have a `Stack<Number>`. You want to push all elements of `src` to the `Stack`. But `src` should be able to be a `Collection<Integer>`. This is why you choose `? extends E` here.

For the method `popAll` imagine you have a `Stack<Integer>`. You want to pop all elements of the `Stack` to `dest`. But `dest` should be able to be a `Collection<Number>`. This is why you choose `? super E` here.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the answer to the question "Which types are subtypes of `SomeClass`?".  This is obviously an interesting question in Java since much of the power of the language comes from the ability to substitute sub types.  Now, with

```
SomeClass<T extends OtherClass>
```

the subtypes are all those `SomeClass<S>` where S is a subtype of T.  For example, the subtypes of

```
SomeClass<T extends List>
```

include SomeClass<LinkedList> and SomeClass<ArrayList>.  But with

```
SomeClass<T super OtherClass>
```

the subtypes are all those `SomeClass<S>` where S is a supertype of T.  For example, the subtypes of

```
SomeClass<T super LinkedList>
```

include `SomeClass<List>` and `SomeClass<Collection>`.

Answer (score 1):

tangens' answer is correct, this is just (perhaps) useful information to accompany that answer.

There is a good explanation of how to use the two different wildcards in Josh Bloch's Effective Java 2nd Edition. It is also described in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi_I7oD_uGI) video.

A mnemonic he uses is PECS - Producer Extends, Consumer Super. This is explained in the video and the book. This is a paraphrasing of one of the slides used in the talk:

---

PECS - Producer `extends` Consumer `super`

- For a `T` producer use `Foo<? extends T>`
- For a `T` consumer use `Foo<? super T>`

This only applies to input parameters, don't use wildcard types as return types.

---

Answer (score 0):

- In the first case, OtherClass and any *subclass* is applicable as type parameter. This is useful for collections, where you want to restrict elements to `Figure` (including `Rectangle` and `Circle`) but not any other objects that are not figures. Thus we limit the collection to `Group<? extends Figure>`.
- In the latter case, OtherClass and any *superclass* is applicable as type parameter. This is useful if you need to pass a `Comparator` to a collection of figures: this comparator should only assume that the elements are figures or more general. A comparators that expected every object to be `Object` or `Figure` will work, but a comparator that assumes that all elements are `Rectangle` will fail if it encounters for example a `Circle`. Thus we limit the comparator to `Comparator<? super Figure>`.