# Java predicate - match against first predicate

Tags: java, java-8

can you help me to build a condition. This is the example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
list.add(4);
```

I have 2 predicates.

```
ArrayList<Predicate<Integer>> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(x -> x == 4);
predicates.add(x -> x == 1);
```

I want to find first element that match first predicate. 
(In this example that would be 4)

How can this be done?

Comment: And what is the issue? Why are `predicate2` and `predicate3` relevant if only `predicate1` is to be used? Are they in a list? You can still refer to the linked question for how to get the first element satisfying a predicate.

Comment: @Tunaki all predicates will be used. I want first element that matches first condition. I will edit my post so they will be in array.

Comment: Something like: `Optional<Integer> result = list.stream().filter(predicate1).findFirst();`

Comment: Well, refer to the linked question then, it also asks about finding the first element of a list matching a predicate ([to get the first element of the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503363/how-can-i-get-a-first-element-from-a-sorted-list)).

Comment: @Tunaki But I want first element that matches first Predicate. In My case I want 4, not 1. ( 1 is the first element, but I want 4 to be found )

Maybe I should foreach over predicates and test 1 by 1.

Comment: Exactly. The first element that matches the predicate, this is what the linked question also asks, please refer to it. Take a look at what [Alexey commented as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048976/java-predicate-match-against-first-predicate#comment67374277_40048976).

Comment: Well, you keep repeating that you want the first element matching the *first predicate* and repeatedly fail to explain the relevance of that list of predicates. Get the first predicate like you get the first *anything* from a `List`: `get(0)`, i.e. `Predicate<Integer> theOnlyRelevantPredicate = predicates.get(0);` Then, proceed like there never was a list of multiple predicates…