# Generics in Collection

Tags: java, generics

Here is my program.  I am not sure why I am getting a compile time error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List< ? extends Number > list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(6); // Compile Time Error

    System.out.println(list);

  }
}
```

But the following program works fine

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List< ? super Number > list = new ArrayList<Number>();

    list.add(6); 

    System.out.println(list);

    }
}
```

**Error from Eclipse:**

Here is the error description from Eclipse:

> The method add(int, capture#1-of ? extends Number) in the type List is not 
>    applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the actual compile time error

Comment: In my first program the compile time error is coming at line 8. I have also given a comment there.

Comment: But what is the text of the error?

Comment: (Note if you do something like `list.remove(6);` something you might not expect will happen.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Cute, but that is a totally separate issue (overload resolution choosing between primitive or boxed) `list.remove((Integer)6)` works as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's because what you are doing in the first case **isn't type safe**. You have declared `list` as a `List` of "some subclass of `Number`", and then tried to insert an `Integer` into it. There is absolutely no guarantee that `Integer` is compatible with the actual run-time type of the underlying list. The compiler stops you here because what you are doing **doesn't make any sense**.

Consider, as an extreme example:

```
List< ? extends Object > list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add("Hello, World!");
```

If this were to work, you would have a `List<Integer>` with a `String` in it!

If you really want it to work, you have to tell the compiler you know what you are doing by casting:

```
((List<Integer>)list).add(6);
```

But even then you will still get a warning about type safety.

The second case works because the list is guaranteed to be "some superclass of Number". `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`, so it can be implicitly converted to any superclass (including `Number` itself), so there is no risk that the value is incompatible with the actual type of the list.

For further information, you may want to read up on the difference between [covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

Comment: If you do something like this

     'List< ? extends Object > list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ((List<String>)list).add("Hello, World!");'

should not it give ClassCastException ?

Comment: Nope, generics are not implemented that way in Java. If you do that, you really do end up with a `List<Integer>` with a `String` in it, and you will get an exception later if you try and retrieve it as an `Integer`. That is why the compiler still gives you a warning. (See [Type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) for more details.)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not clear why it is implemented in that way.

Comment: It's complicated, but basically generics in Java only exist at compile time. At runtime (when the cast happens) the generic type is "erased" and both `List<Integer>` and `List<String>` are just `List`s, so the cast works fine. The actual exception occurs when you try to use that `String` as an `Integer`, which definitely isn't fine.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add anything to a `List` that has a `? extends ...` as part of its generic type.

Let's look at this:

```
List< ? extends Number > list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Note that the actual `List` you're using is an `ArrayList<Integer>`. It should not be possible to put something else in this list that is not an `Integer`. Yet, the type `List<? extends Number>` would allow you to add for example a `Double` to the list, because `Double` also extends `Number`.

For more details, see the following in Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ: [Which methods and fields are accessible/inaccessible through a reference variable of a wildcard parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ304)

Comment: Thanks i have already saw that, but since i am a novice programmer so i couldn't understand it properly

Answer (score 1):

Its about the `super` and the `extends`. Compare [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910892/1515052).

you can also look it up by the [Wildcards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_%28Java%29).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work:

```
List< ? extends Number > list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(6); // Compile Time Error
```

because if it did you could arrive in a situation like this.

```
class Apple extends Number  {}

List< ? extends Number > list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(new Apple()); //if it were to work, you'd have apples in what you'd think was a list of integers
```