# Java Generic with ArrayList <? extends A> add element

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have classes `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` where `B` extends `A`, `C` extends `A` and `D` extends `A`.

I have the following `ArrayList`s each with a few elements in them:

```
ArrayList<B> b;
ArrayList<? extends A> mix = b;
```

I intended for the variable `mix` to contain elements of type `B`, `C` or `D`. I tried to add an element of type `C` into `mix` like this:

```
mix.add(anElementOfTypeC);
```

But the IDE doesn't allow me to do so and it says:

> anElementOfTypeC cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method of invocation
>   conversion where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable: CAP#1 extends A from
>   capture of ? extends A

Did I use the `<? extends A>` correctly? How can I resolve this?

Comment: From your code extract, `mix` is actually an `ArrayList<B>` here...

Comment: During your research - if you did some, did you came through this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910892/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-extends-in-java-generics ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`ArrayList<? extends A>` means an ArrayList of some unknown type that extends `A`.
That type might not be `C`, so you can't add a `C` to the ArrayList.

In fact, since you don't know what the ArrayList is supposed to contain, you can't add *anything* to the ArrayList.

If you want an ArrayList that can hold any class that inherits `A`, use a `ArrayList<A>`.

Comment: can't add anything is a bit too strict. We can add `null`, or we can add `list.get(0)` back to the list. I know I'm picking too much. ;)

Comment: And yet you can declare `Class<? extends A> c = B.class`... Generics give me a real headache :/

Comment: @RohitJain: no, you cannot add `list.get(0)` back to the list

Comment: @JBNizet: I know what you're talking about; but it's not what the topic of the comment is talking about. That's `List<T>`, not `List<? extends A>`, which is the topic of the comment.

Comment: @newacct Re-read the code. The method appends an element from a `List<? extends A>` to this list. mix is of type `List<? extends A>`.

Comment: @JBNizet: I know what the code says. I am not disputing the fact that the element came from a `List<? extends A>`. But at the point where you are "adding `list.get(0)`", it is a `List<T>`. That's the difference.

Answer (score 12):

It is not possible to add elements in collection that uses `? extends`.

`ArrayList<? extends A>` means that this is an `ArrayList` of type (**exactly one** type) that extends `A`. So you can be sure, that when you call `get` method, you'll get something that **is** A. But you can't add something because you don't know what exactly the `ArrayList` contains.

Answer (score 7):

> Did I use the `<? extends A>` correctly?

`List<? extends A> list;` means that the 'list' refers to an object implemented interface List, and the list can hold elements inherited from class A (including A). In other words the following statements are correct:

```
List<? extends A> listA1 = new ArrayList<A>();
List<? extends A> listB1 = new ArrayList<B>();
List<? extends A> listC1 = new ArrayList<C>();
List<? extends A> listD1 = new ArrayList<D>();
```

Java generics are a compile-time strong type checking.
The compiler uses generics to make sure that your code doesn't add the wrong objects into a collection.

You tried to add `C` in `ArrayList<B>`

```
listB1.add(new C());
```

If it were allowed the object `ArrayList<B>` would contain different object types (B,C).
That is why the **reference** listB1 works in 'read-only' mode. Additionally you could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures).

> how to resolve this?

```
List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just declare:

```
ArrayList<A> mix = new ArrayList<A>();
```

You can add any element of class A or any of its subclasses into such a list. It is just that when you get from that list, you will only be able to call methods available on `A`.

Note that `A` is not limited to being a "full fledged" class: it can be an abstract class or even an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can  create the array list of super class type. so you can do this.

```
ArrayList<A> arrayList=new ArrayList<A>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example and choose as per your requirement

```
package com.generic;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SuperExtendTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    public void test() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Parent> parents=new ArrayList<>();
        parents.add(new Parent());
        parents.add(new Child());
        //parents.add(new GrandParent()); Not allowed

        ArrayList<Parent> p=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Child> c=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<GrandParent> gp=new ArrayList<>();

        testExtendP(p);
        //testExtendP(c); Not allowed only super type allowed no child
        testExtendP(gp);

        testExtends(c);
        testExtends(p);
        //testExtends(gp); Not allowed because GrantParent does not extends Parent
    }

    /**
     * This Method allowed get operations for Parent 
     * No add 
     * 
     */
    public void testExtends(ArrayList<? extends Parent> list) throws Exception {
    /*  list.add(new Child());
        list.add(new Parent());
        list.add(new GrandParent());
        // can not add
        */
        Child c=(Child) list.get(0);
        Parent parent=list.get(0);
        GrandParent gp=list.get(0);
        /**
         * Unsafe collection way
         */
        ArrayList list2=new ArrayList();
        list.addAll(list2);
    }

    /**
     * This Method allowed add operations for Parent and it's sub types and on get it gives Object type 
     * 
     */
    public void testExtendP(ArrayList<? super Parent> list) throws Exception {
        list.add(new Child());
        list.add(new Parent());
        //list.add(new GrandParent());
        /*can not add because GrandParent can not be converted to Parent type
         * 
         * The method add(capture#3-of ? super Parent) in the type ArrayList<capture#3-of ? super Parent> is not applicable for the arguments (GrandParent)
         * 
         */

        Child c=(Child) list.get(0);
        Parent parent=(Parent) list.get(0);
        GrandParent gp=(GrandParent) list.get(0);
        Object obj=list.get(0);

        /**
         * Unsafe collection way
         */
        ArrayList list2=new ArrayList();
        list.addAll(list2);
    }

    /**
     * This Method allowed all operations for Parent and it's sub types 
     * 
     */
    public void testDirect(ArrayList<Parent> list) throws Exception {
        list.add(new Child());
        list.add(new Parent());
        //list.add(new GrandParent()); 
        /*
         * Can not add GrandParent (Normal generic rule)
         */
    }

}
class GrandParent{

}

class Parent extends GrandParent{

}
class Child extends Parent{

}
```