# If you're trying to have list with various child classes of a single parent class, how would you do it?

Tags: java

Should you use

```
List<ParentClass> foo = new ArrayList<ParentClass>
foo.add(ChildClassObject)
```

or

```
List<? extends ParentClass> bar - new ArrayList<ParentClass>
bar.add(ChildClassObject)
```

Also, could someone explain more to me the latter parameterization of List?

Answer (score 4):

Use the first approach. The second doesn't allow you to add any element. This is because the second approach uses an unknown type that extends `ParentClass` and cannot assure that the elements to be stored are from this type.

More info:

- [Java Generic with ArrayList <? extends A> add element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14306166/1065197)

Answer (score 3):

`List<? extends ParentClass>` is a list of *some specific subtype of `ParentClass`*. Since, it's not know what exact specific subtype it is, the compiler won't let you add any object to it.

For starters, it's easy to mistake it with *any subtype of `ParentClass`* and wonder why they can't add the instances of the subtypes.

For instance, suppose you have a following class hierarchy -

```
class P { }
class A extends P { }
class B extends P { }
```

Now if you declare a a list as follows -

```
List<? extends P> l = ...;
```

it means `l` is a list of some specific subtype of `P`, which could be either `A` or `B` (or even `P` itself), but the compiler doesn't know exactly which one. So, you can't add anything to it, because the chance is that you could be adding an instance of `B` to a list of `A`s creating some heap pollution.

You would declare such a list when you are only interested in reading the elements of list as `P`'s instances.