# GenericsAdd (capture <? extends ConstraintViolation>) in Set cannot be applied to (ConstraintViolation)

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```
UniqueConstraintViolation violation = new UniqueConstraintViolationImpl();
Set<? extends javax.validation.ConstraintViolation> violations = new HashSet<UniqueConstraintViolation>();
violations.add(violation);
throw new javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException(violations);
```

where UniqueConstraintViolation is interface extended javax.validation.ConstraintViolation 
and UniqueConstraintViolationImpl is class implemented UniqueConstraintViolation

While compiling I get following error

> java:42: error: no suitable method found for
>   add(UniqueConstraintViolation)
>               violations.add(violation);
>                         ^
>       method Collection.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; UniqueConstraintViolation cannot be converted to CAP#1 )
>       method Set.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; UniqueConstraintViolation cannot be converted to CAP#1 )   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>       CAP#1 extends ConstraintViolation from capture of ? extends ConstraintViolation
>   C:\workspace\zcts-travel\crud-rest\src\main\java\ru\zcts\crud\AbstractResource.java:43: error: incompatible types: Set cannot be converted to Set>
>               throw new javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException(violations);
>
> ```
>                                                                 ^   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
> CAP#1 extends ConstraintViolation from capture of ? extends ConstraintViolation
> ```

I just want to pass in javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException constructor the Set with my own implementation of javax.validation.ConstraintViolation.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So having your constraints:

```
interface UniqueConstraintViolation extends ConstraintViolation<YourClass> {

}

public class UniqueConstraintViolationImpl implements UniqueConstraintViolation {
    /* your impl here */
}
```

This will compile:

```
UniqueConstraintViolation violation = new UniqueConstraintViolationImpl();

Set<UniqueConstraintViolation> violations = new HashSet<UniqueConstraintViolation>();
violations.add(violation);
throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
```

Comment: that hurts my eyes, even dropping the constraints would be better than wildcasting everything

Comment: @ETartaren the problem was in the `Set` declaration

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<? extends javax.validation.ConstraintViolation> violations = new HashSet<UniqueConstraintViolation>();
violations.add(violation);
```

you can't add anything other than `null` to `voilations` because it uses `? extends javax.validation.ConstraintViolation`.

read here : [Java Generic with ArrayList <? extends A> add element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306166/java-generic-with-arraylist-extends-a-add-element)

Comment: to solve the problem, change ``Set<? extends ConstraintViolation> violations = ...;`` to ``Set<ConstraintViolation> violations = new HashSet<>();``

Comment: then `violations` won't be able to refer to `new HashSet<UniqueConstraintViolation>();`

Comment: let type inference do it's work: ``new HashSet<>();`` thanks for the note.