# Error in populating the list which extends the generic type

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

I have a list which extends the generic type and I have to loop through this list and filter it. After filtering I have to create another filtered list and set it for the form. The problem here is that I am not able to add the object in the list when traversing. Below is the error :

```
The method add(capture#8-of ? extends Element) in the type List<capture#8-of ? extends Element> is not applicable for the arguments (Element)
```

updatedList object is the list where I have to add the Element object after traversing through the full list. I am getting the compiler error on the following line :

```
updatedList.add(newList);
```

Below is the full code :

```
final List<? extends Element> list = elementService.fullTextSearch(query);
long id = LoggedUser.element().getGroup().getId();
if(LoggedUser.hasUser() && id == 2)
{
    List<? extends Element> updatedList = new ArrayList<Element>();
    System.err.println("id of the group for search :" + id);
        for(Element newList : list)
        {
            if(newList.getUser().getAdminUserId() == LoggedUser.element().getUser().getId())
            updatedList.add(newList);
        }
        System.err.println("account admin list "+ updatedList);
        context.getRequest().setAttribute("elements", updatedList);

}
```

Comment: This is java. Why tag C#?

Comment: because the concept is same in the C# also.

Comment: You should only tag the language in which the code is in. The concept might be also the same in so many other languages

Comment: ok thanks for the information.

Comment: For the record, this aspect of generics is very different from C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306166/java-generic-with-arraylist-extends-a-add-element)

Comment: Just change the type of `updatedList` to `List<Element>`.