# Java generics wildcards with upper and lower bounds

Tags: java, wildcard, bounds

Lets suppose class C extends B, B extends A.

For given function:

```
public static void add(List<? extends B> list) {
    list.add(new A()); //Doesn't compile
    list.add(new B()); //Doesn't compile
    list.add(new C()); //Doesn't compile
}
```

Why it's impossible to add any element ? I understand

```
List<? extends B> list
```

as a list of elements of type B or C.

For super bound:

```
public static void add2(List<? super B> list) {
    list.add(new A()); //doesn't compile
    list.add(new B());
    list.add(new C());
}
```

I understand

```
List<? super B> list
```

as a list with elements of type A or B.

I don't understand how does it work :/

Comment: It's not impossible to add any element in the first case: you can add `null`.

Comment: Why its impossible to add any element in the first case ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306166/java-generic-with-arraylist-extends-a-add-element

Comment: @user109447 because a `List<SomeOtherSubclassOfB>` is a `List<? extends B>`; none of `A`, `B` or `C` would be safe to add to such a list.