# Collections sort/binarysearch method

Tags: java, generics

I have a query on Collections API binary search and sort method declarations.
There is upper bound wildcard use with `list` parameter in `binarySearch`.
But the `list` parameter in the `sort` method does not use an upper bound wildcard. Why are these different?

For `sort`, `list` does not use upper bound wildcard.

```java
static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

For `binarySearch`, `list` uses an upper bound wildcard.

```java
static <T> int binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

I am wondering why upper bound is needed here if it is not needed in the `sort` method.

Comment: `binarySearch()` only needs to read from the passed `List`, but the `sort()` needs to swap elements around, and thus needs to read and write from the `List`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because when you have a `List<? extends T>`, you can't add elements to or remove elements from it, because you don't know the type of the elements in that list. It could be just `T`, it could be `Object`, or any superclass of `T` in between. See [Java Generic with `ArrayList<? extends A>` add element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306166/java-generic-with-arraylist-extends-a-add-element/20589760) for more information.

As [@Lino - Vote don't say Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5515060/lino-vote-dont-say-thanks) said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929535/collections-sort-binarysearch-method#comment111284175_62929535), this is fine with `binarySearch`, because it doesn't have to add or remove elements from the given list - as long as the comparator can compare each element, it's happy. However, `sort` does have to move elements around, so it needs the list to be of a known type.

<sub>This doesn't mean it's actually taken advantage of: `java.util.Collections.java` [sources](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l228) (OpenJDK 8)</sub>