# In java generics what is the difference between the wildcard symbols: <? extends Object> and <? extends T> ?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to learn generics and I had some questions about wildcards and their use.

What is the difference between the wildcards for upper and lower bounds and specifically what is the difference between: `<? extends Object>` and `<? extends T>` in java?

Comment: This seems a bit general. Did you study generics thoroughly first? You'd know it if you had  - canonical tut - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: correct me if im' wrong -  T is usually used in examples , in real life it should be a meaningful name...

Comment: @Adel You're wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here for your question on "upper and lower bounds" - [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910892/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-extends-in-java-generics).

For an overview on generics [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490091/java-generics)

As for the difference between `<? extends Object>` and `<? extends T>`, the former is a type that is bound by the type `java.lang.Object` whereas the latter is bound by the type variable `T` - meaning you can satisfy by any type that extends `java.lang.Object`(which is all Java types) in the former  and in the latter, you can satisfy by any type that extends the type `T`. Remember that T can be anything - even java.lang.Object.

Answer (score 0):

`<? extends Object>` is *ALMOST* useless. All that means is you're working with something that is not a primitive type.  `<? extends T>` means you're working with an object that is of type `T` or a subclass of `T` and has whatever methods and fields `T` has.

`<? extends T>` is useful to declare what an Object is expected to contain. It limits the scope of the container or the method which adds funcionality to the method/container.

For Example:

```java
public class foobination<T extends foo>
{
   private <? extends T> foo;

   public foobination(T foo)
   {
      this.foo = foo;
   }

   public getFoo() { return foo; }

   public void myFoobinator(<? extends T> foob)
   {
     foo.bash("foobinator was here");
     foo.setBang(foob.getBang());
   }
}
```

the other common use case would be: `List<? extends T>` Where you're storing a collection of something and you don't know exactly what it is but you do know they will all be a subclass of whatever T is.  That way you at least have some idea of what to expect to get back out of the collection.

Comment: Generics don't work with primitives in Java

Comment: I stand corrected. I guess that means `<? extends Object>` is useless after all, unless there is some other subtlety I'm missing.

Comment: @NullUserException Which is why the second sentence is correct, no?

Comment: @EdwardThomson The main problem I have with this answer is that it does little to explain what `<? extends T>` does and why/where/when it should be used.

Comment: @NullUserException I agree that's the case, but I think your statement about generics falls in the same bucket:  it's technically correct, which is admittedly the best kind of correct, but it's not particularly helpful to answering or elucidating.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Which is why it was just a comment