# Problems with Java generics and collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a class that represents a tree-like structure, the essential bits look like this:

```
public Node<T> placeAll(Collection<T> elements){    
    for (T e : elements)
        addElement(e);

    // LOG/DEBUG etc
    return root;
}

public void addElement(T el) {
    Node<T> node = new Node<T>(el);
    addElement(root, node);
}

private void addElement(Node<T> parent, Node<T> child) {
    // .... PLACE THE NODE
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine when I place the nodes one by one in a test case:

```
public void test() {

    List<Integer> s1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
    // 13 more lists
    List<Integer> s15 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 221, 251); 

    Hypergraph<Object> hg = new Hypergraph<>(...);

        hg.addElement(s1);
        System.out.println(hg.getRoot().toStringTree());
        System.out.println();
              .
              .
              .
        hg.addElement(s15);
        System.out.println(hg.getRoot().toStringTree());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

If I add the following line 
`hg.placeAll(Arrays.asList(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13,s14,s15));`

to my test case, I get an error regarding the use of generics:

> `The method placeAll(Collection<Object>) in the type Hypergraph<Object> is not applicable for the arguments (List<List<Integer>>)`

I don't quite understand this... If `addElement(T el)` works fine when I call it with `T` resolved to `List<Integer>`, why does `List<List<Integer>>` comply to `placeAll(Collection<T> c)`? Considering that `List<T>` is a `Collection<T>` I can't make sense out of this..

Comment: @tobias_k it works, but could you explain why that's how it needs to be? if addElement takes T as an argument, placeAll should then be accepting a collection of Ts, intuitively speaking

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1910892/1639625

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the method expects a `Collection<Object>` (as `T` seems to be `Object` in your example), but you are passing a `Collection<List<Integer>>`. And while a `List<Integer>` is an `Object`, a `Collection<List<Integer>>` is *not* a subclass of a `Collection<Object>`.

Change the method signature to accept a `Collection<? extends T>`, then it should work.

```
public Node<T> placeAll(Collection<? extends T> elements) {
```

Comment: Addendum: Actually, it  _should_ work if you do `placeAll(Arrays.asList(...))`, as `asList` should automatically return a collection of the right type. Maybe you actually did `List<List<Integer>> foo = Arrays.asList(...); placeAll(foo)`? Or maybe it depends on the Java version.

Comment: Nope, the code is taken directly from the class: `hg.placeAll(Arrays.asList(...);`. On a side note I don't get the point with _And while a `List<Integer>` is an `Object`, a `Collection<List<Integer>>` is not a subclass of a `Collection<Object>`._ I get that Collection<X> is not a subclass of Collection<Y>, but if X is a subclass of Y, it should still be valid, no?

Comment: @posdef See it this way: If your method signature was `placeAll(Collection<Object>)`, then it would be possible to add an `Object` into the `Collection<List<Integer>>` inside the method! With `Collection<? extends Object>` this is not possible.

Comment: I see, thnx for the additional explanation