# Java generics super keyword

Tags: java, generics

I went through these topics

- [Generics..? Super T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591004/generics-super-t/591011)
- [Bounding generics with 'super' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800369/bounding-generics-with-super-keyword)

However, I still seem to be kind of lost with `super` keyword:

1. When we declare a collection like that:

   ```
   List<? super Number> list = null;
   list.add(new Integer(0)); // this compiles
   list.add(new Object()); // this doesn't compile
   ```

shouldn't it be the opposite - we have a list that contains some objects (of unknown type) which are parents of `Number`. So `Object` should fit (since it is the parent of `Number`), and `Integer` shouldn't. The opposite is the case for some reason.

2. Provided we have the following code

   ```
   static void test(List<? super Number> param) {
     param.add(new Integer(2));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<String> sList = new ArrayList<String>();
     test(sList);            // will never compile, however...
   }
   ```

It is impossible to compile the above code (and my sanity suggests that this is the right behaviour), but the basic logic could prove the opposite:

`String is Object, Object is superclass of Number. So String should work.`

I know this is crazy but isn't this the reason why they didn't allow `<S super T>` constructs? If yes, then why `<? super T>` is allowed?

Could someone help me restore the missing part of this logic chain?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The bounded wildcard in `List<? super Number>` can capture `Number` and any of its supertypes. Since `Number extends Object implements Serializable`, this means that the only types that are currently capture-convertible by `List<? super Number>` are:

- `List<Number>`
- `List<Object>`
- `List<Serializable>`

Note that you can `add(Integer.valueOf(0))` to any of the above types. however, you *CAN'T* `add(new Object())` to a `List<Number>` or a `List<Serializable>`, since that violates the generic type safety rule.

Hence it is *NOT* true that you can `add` any supertype of `Number` to a `List<? super Number>`; that's simply not how bounded wildcard and capture conversion work. You don't declare a `List<? super Number>` because you may want to add an `Object` to it (you can't!); you do because you want to add `Number` objects to it (i.e. it's a "consumer" of `Number`), and simply a `List<Number>` is too restrictive.

#### References

- [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [What is a bounded wildcard?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103)
  - [When would I use a wildcard parameterized type with a lower bound?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ204) ("When a concrete parameterized type would be too restrictive.")
  - [Why is there no lower bound for type parameters?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107) ("Because it does not make sense.")
- [JLS 5.1.10 Capture Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.10)

#### See also

- *[Effective Java 2nd Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility*

  - "PECS stands for producer-`extends`, consumer-`super`

#### Related questions

- Too many to list, PECS, `new Integer(0)` vs `valueOf`, etc

Comment: I can't confirm if your answer is right or wrong because it is too confusing and assumes too much knowledge. This question would not be asked if we could understand an answer like this!

Comment: @AlexWorden this answer technically is very correct, no question about it, if you want a lightweight explanation, may be [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64490493/1059372)

Answer (score 26):

For the first part `List<Number>` fits in `List<? super Number>` but you can't add an `Object` to a `List<Number>`. That's why you can't add an `Object` to `List<? super Number>`.

On the other hand you can add every subclass of `Number` (`Number` included) to your list.

For the second part, `String` is an `Object`, but `String` isn't a superclass of `Number`.

If it worked like this, as every class is a subclass of `Object`, `super` would have no meaning.

---

## Let's see every possible cases with `List<? super Number>` :

---

- The passed list is a **`List<Object>`**

  - **`List<Object>` will work**
  - `Object` fits in `<? super Number>`
  - You can add any subtype of `Number` to a `List<Object>`
  - Even if you could also add `String` in it the only thing you're sure of is that you can add any subclass of `Number`.

---

- The passed list is a **`List<Number>`** :

  - **`List<Number>` will work**
  - `Number` fits in `<? super Number>`
  - You can add any subtype of `Number` to a `List<Number>`

---

- The passed list is a **`List<Integer>`** (or any subclass of `Number`):

  - **`List<Integer>` won't work**
  - Integer is a subclass of `Number` so it is exactly what we want to avoid
  - Even if an `Integer` fits in a `Number` you wouldn't be abble to add any subclass of `Number` in a `List<Integer>` (for example a `Float`)
  - `super` doesn't mean a subclass.

---

- The passed list is a **`List<String>`** (or any class not extending `Number` nor in the "super hierarchy" of `Number` (ie. `Number` and `Object`) :

  - **`List<String>` won't work**
  - `String` doesn't fit in `Number` "super hierarchy"
  - Even if `String` fits in `Object` (which is a super class of `Number`) you woudln't be sure to be able to add a `Number` to a `List` that contain any subclass from one of the super classes of `Number`)
  - `super` doesn't mean any subclass of one of the super classes, it only means one of the super classes.

---

How does it work ?

You could say that as long as you can add any subclass of `Number` with your typed `List`, it respects the `super` keyword.

Comment: @Vuntic, It's kind of hard to be perfectly clear with generics, but I updated my answer and I tried :)

Comment: Thanks Colin, this made it more clear for me. This topic needs experimenting with it a bit to understand it fully

Comment: thats a good way of explaining genercis, giving all possible scenarios, but You could add some colors, and bold formatings to make things more clear to read ;)

Answer (score 10):

I didn't get it for a while. Many of the answers here, and the other questions show specifically when and where certain usages are errors, but not so much why.

This is how I finally got it. If I have a function that adds `Number`s to a `List`, I might want to add them of type `MySuperEfficientNumber` which is my own custom class that implements `Number` (but is not a subclass of `Integer`). Now the caller might not know anything about `MySuperEfficientNumber`, but as long as they know to treat the elements added to the list as nothing more specific than `Number`, they'll be fine.

If I declared my method as:

```
public static void addNumbersToList(List<? extends Number> numbers)
```

Then the caller could pass in a `List<Integer>`. If my method added a `MySuperEfficientNumber` to the end of `numbers`, then the caller would no longer have a `List` of `Integer`s and the following code wouldn't work:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
addNumbersToList(numbers);

// The following would return a MySuperEfficientNumber not an Integer
Integer i = numbers.get(numbers.size()-1)
```

Obviously this can't work. And the error would be inside the `addNumbersToList` method. You'd get something like:

```
The method add... is not applicable for the arguments (MySuperEfficientNumber)
```

Because `numbers` could be any specific kind of `Number`, not necessarily something that `MySuperEfficientNumber` is compatible with. If I flipped the declaration around to use `super`, the method would compile without error, but the caller's code would fail with:

```
The method addNumbersToList(List<? super Number>)... is not applicable for the arguments (List<Integer>)
```

Because my method is saying, "Don't think that your `List` can be of anything more specific than `Number`. I might add all sorts of weird `Number`s to the list, you'll just have to deal with it. If you want to think of them as something even more general than `Number` -- like `Object` -- that's fine, I guarantee they'll be at least `Number`s, but you can treat them more generally if you want."

Whereas `extends` is saying, "I don't really care what kind of `List` you give me, as long as each element is at least a `Number`. It can be any kind of `Number`, even your own weird, custom, made-up `Number`s. As long as they implement that interface, we're good. I'm not going to be adding anything to your list since I don't know what actual concrete type you're using there."

Answer (score 6):

`List<? super Number>` means that the reference type of the variable suggests we have a list of Numbers, Objects or Serializables.

The reason you can't add an Object, is because the compiler does not know WHICH of these classes are in the generic definition of the actual instantiated object, so it only allows you to pass Number or subtypes of Number, like Double, Integer and so on.

Let's say we have a method that returns a `List<? super Number>`. The creation of the object inside the method is encapsulated from our view, we just can't say if it is something like this:

`List<? super Number> returnValue = new LinkedList<Object>();`

or

`List<? super Number> returnValue = new ArrayList<Number>();`

So, the generic type could be Object or Number. In both cases, we would be allowed to add Number, but only in one case we would be allowed to add Object.

You have to distinguish between the reference type and the actual object type in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

There are two angles here: what you can *put* into a collection and what you can *get* from a collection, when bounded types are involved.

---

Let's look at the `? extends Number` case first. When a collection with such bounds is defined, what we know is that : every element will have an upper bound as `Number`. We don't know the exact type (might be an `Integer/Long/etc`), but we do know, for sure, that its upper bound is `Number`.

So *reading* from such a collection gets us a `Number`. This is the only guaranteed type we can get from it.

Writing to such a collection is prohibited. But why? Didn't I say that while we read - we will always get a `Number`, so why prohibit writing to it? The situation is slightly more involved here:

```
 List<Integer> ints = ....;
 List<? extends Number> numbers = ints;
 numbers.add(12D); // add a double in here
```

If addition would have been allowed into `numbers`, you could have effectively added a `Double` in a `List of Integers`.

---

Now to your example:

```
 List<? super Number> list = null;
 list.add(new Integer(0));
 list.add(new Object());
```

We know about `list` that it contains a certain *supertype* of `Number`, for example `Object`.

*Reading* from such a list would get us a certain type `X`, where `X` would be a parent of `Number`. So what would that be? You can't really know. It could be a theoretical `MyNumber extends Number`, or much simpler: an `Object`. Since you can't know for sure, the only safe thing to read from that would be the super-type of everything - `Object`.

What is a bit weird may be :

```
List<? super String> list = ...;
String s = list.get(0); // fails, compiler does not care that String is final
```

*Writing* to it is slightly more complicated, but only slightly. Remember what we know is inside that `list`: it's a type that `Number` *extends/implements* (if it were an interface), so you can always assign a *subtype* (or `Number` itself) to that *supertype*.

```
             Some type X
                 / \
                  |
                Number
                 / \
                  |
    Some type Y that we an put in here
```

Answer (score 2):

`List<? super Number>` is such a `List<AncestorOfNumber>` where we can implicitely cast each `Number` to its super type `AncestorOfNumber`.

Consider this: What generic type needs to be `????` in the following example?

```
InputStream mystream = ...;

void addTo(List<????> lsb) {
    lsb.add(new BufferedInputStream(mystream));
}

List<BufferedInputStream> lb = new ArrayList<>();
List<InputStream> li = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> lo = new ArrayList<>();

...
{ addTo(lb); addTo(li); addTo(lo); }
```

The answer: `????` is anything to which we can cast `BufferedInputStream`, which is that very same or one of its ancestors: `? super BufferedInputStream`

Answer (score 2):

May I give a very simple Example.

```
public void add(List<? super Number> list) {
}
```

this **will allow** these calls

```
add(new LinkedList<Number>());
```

**and everything above** Number like

```
add(new LinkedList<Object>());
```

but nothing below the hierarchy so **not**

```
add(new LinkedList<Double>());
```

or

```
add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
```

So since its not clear for the program to know whether you give a List with Number or Object the compiler cannot allow you to add anything above Number to it.

For example a List would not accept an Object in spite of Object who would accept a Number. But since this is not clear the only valid input would be Number and its sub types.