# Java method generics understanding

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to figure out why I can't I use `super` in a generic method declaration? See the example below, it doesn't compile, but I'm not sure why.

```
public class A<E> {
    public <T extends A> void test1(T t) {   // Compiles fine
    }
    public <T super A> void test2(T t) {     // Compilation error??
    }
    public <T super A> <T> void test3(T t) { // Compilation error??
    }
}

class A {}
....
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword

Comment: Syntax error on token "super", , expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it, if a method could have the signature

```
public <T super A> void test2(T t) {
}
```

then it could take any object as argument. Why? Because, for example, you can always infer `T` as `Object` (`Object` is a supertype of `A`), and any object is an instance of `Object`, so it works. So declaring it this way would be pretty redundant. You could just write

```
public void test2(Object t) {
}
```

for the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between type parameters and type arguments. The use of wildcards (`super` and `extends`) is for type arguments, that is, you declare them at the call site when you're actually defining the corresponding value of a type parameter. Alternatively, the keyword `extends` can be used for type parameter constraints.

### Type Parameters vs Type Arguments

As such, in the definition `class List<T>{}`, `T` is called a type parameter. Whe you a declare a reference of type `List`, at the call site you are allowed to provide a type argument for `T`, which can be an invariant (i.e. `List<String> jedis`) or a wildcard with super or with extends (i.e. `List<? extends Number> myNums`, `List<? super String> names`).

### Type Parameter Constraints

The keyword `extends` can also be used in a totally different purpose to declare constraints for a given type parameter. For instance, the declaration:

```
class List<T extends CharSequence>{}
```

The type parameter `T` is constrained. This would imply that whenever you declare a type argument for your type parameter `T`, it must be of type `CharSequence` or any of its subtypes.

As such `List<String>` would be valid declaration, but `List<Integer>` would not.

The use of the keyword `super` is not allowed in the declaration of type parameter constraints, probably because it does not make a lot of sense, in your declaration, what could be a valid type argument for `T` that is not `A` itself?