# Use of super in Comparator in java

Tags: java, comparator

I understand in

```
Comparator < ? super T> comp
```

it returns the maximum element of the given collection, according to the order defined by the specified comparator. But I don't understand the purpose of the

> super T

Could anyone possibly explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In here `< ? super T>` means *generics* - NOT comparisons.

It means you have a `Comparator` with a generic type of `? super T` (something that <strike>extends</strike> is super typed by `T`), as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3847162/572670)

`comp` is the variable name (binding).

So basically in here `Comparator < ? super T>` is a *type* and `comp` is an *identifier* (variable name), that is of type `Comparator <? super T>`

---

For more info: [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 20):

The term `? super T` means "unknown type that is, or is a super class of, T", which in generics parlance means its lower bound is T.

This signature is used because T may be assigned to, and compared with, any variable whose type is, or is a super class of, T. Ie if a Comparator can accept a super class of T in its compare() method, you can pass in a T.

This follows the PECS mnemonic: "Producer Extends, Consumer Super", which means that producers of things should work with things that have an *upper* bound ( ? extends T) and consumers (like comparator implementations that *use* things) should work with *lower* bounds ( ? super T).

Answer (score 1):

Lets take an example

```
interface Fruit {
    int getPrice();
}

class Orange implements Fruit {
    int price;

    public Orange(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}

interface Apple extends Fruit {
    int getAppleQuality();
}

class WineSapApple implements Apple {

    public int price, quality;
    public WineSapApple(int price, int quality) {
        this.price = price;
        this.quality = quality;
    }
    @Override
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    @Override
    public int getAppleQuality() {
        return quality;
    }
}

class AppleQualityComparator implements Comparator<Apple> {
    public int compare(Apple a1, Apple a2) {
        return Integer.compare(a1.getAppleQuality(), a2.getAppleQuality());
    }
}

class FruitPriceComparator implements Comparator<Fruit> {
    public int compare(Fruit f1, Fruit f2) {
        return Integer.compare(f1.getPrice(), f2.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Okay now

```
        List<Fruit> fruits = List.of(new WineSapApple(100, 50), new Orange(10));
        Collections.sort(fruits, new FruitPriceComparator());
//        Collections.sort(fruits, new AppleQualityComparator()); compilation error
```

Importantly we want to re use the Comparator declared at super class level

```
    List<Apple> apples = List.of(new WineSapApple(100, 50), new WineSapApple(150, 75));
    Collections.sort(apples, new FruitPriceComparator()); //<--- reason for `? super T`
    Collections.sort(apples, new AppleQualityComparator());
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's use the type of one of [TreeSet's constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)) as an example:

```
TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
```

Imagine that `E` is a String, so we mentally specialize the constructor:

```
TreeSet(Comparator<? super String> comparator)
```

I can instantiate `TreeSet` like this:

```
var mySet = new TreeSet<String>(myStringComparator);
```

Here, `myStringComparator` might look like this.

```
Comparator<String> myStringComparator = new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

The `<? super String>` part of `TreeSet(Comparator<? super String> comparator)` allows us to also provide the constructor with a comparator that compares **super** types of Strings. That's a more general, less-specific, comparator you might say.

For example, [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) is a super type of String, that's why this works, too:

```
Comparator<CharSequence> myCharSeqComparator = new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(CharSequence o1, CharSequence o2) {
        return 0;
    }
};

var mySet2 = new TreeSet<String>(myCharSeqComparator);
```

Hypothetically, if `TreeSet`'s constructor were defined like this:

```
TreeSet(Comparator<E> comparator)
```

which in our example specializes to

```
TreeSet(Comparator<String> comparator)
```

we could **only** provide `Comparator<String>`, but not `Comparator<CharSequence>` or `Comparator<Object>`.

This would be a pity since we might want to use the more general comparators that don't need the specifics of String to be able to compare.