# Generics lower bound ('super') issue?

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java generics super keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword)

I am not able to relate my knowledge with the below sample program. Please see the below sample program then my doubts are below that program.

```
import java.util.*;
class A { }
class B extends A { }
class C extends B { }

public class sampleprog {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<? super A> list1 = new ArrayList<A>();
        list1.add(new A());//valid. ok
        list1.add(new B());//valid, why? it is not super to A?
        list1.add(new C());//valid, why? it is not super to A?

        List<? super B> list2 = new ArrayList<A>();
        list2.add(new A());//not valid. why? it is also super to B!!!
        list2.add(new B());
        list2.add(new C());

        List<? super C> list3 = new ArrayList<C>();
        list3.add(new A());//not valid, why? It is super to A so should be valid!!!
        list3.add(new B());//not valid, why? It is super to A so should be valid!!!
        list3.add(new C());
    }
}
```

My Doubts:
-  As far as I know `? super T` means any class you can add that is super to `T` but here output is different? Even subclass also added successfully that is totally confusing.
- output is not different with list initialization (`List<? super C> list3 = new ArrayList<C>();`) . In this initialization, I assigned list of `A` or `B`, output was same!

Please clear my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"? super T" means any class you can add that must be an instance of T or its sub class.

So `List<? super C> list3 = new ArrayList<C>();` in the list3 either you can add instance of class C or its sub class instances (`SomeClass extends C`).

A parent object list can have its own, child and child of child but a List that has created for a child class can not have its parent object. Hope you are clear now.

Comment: Ya its clear now with the new definition of "? super T" but it is the definition given in scjp kathy sierra "When you use the <? super ...> syntax, you are telling
the compiler that you can accept the type on the right-hand side of super or any
of its supertypes, since—and this is the key part that makes it work—" on Page Number 619!!!
Why she is saying supertypes and you are telling for subtypes?

Comment: let me clear you little later.

Comment: here its explained http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ204

Answer (score 1):

If we use `? super` in a generic declaration, the reference can point to same generic type of collection or super generic type of collection. So everything that passes a IS-A test is valid in this case.

Comment: but "? super B" clearly mentioned that any class that is super to B. So A and other classes should be valid but not C? But as per the output, C is valid!!!

Answer (score 1):

`List<? super B>` means that

```
List<? super B> list1 = new ArrayList<A>();
List<? super B> list1 = new ArrayList<B>();
```

are allowed. `ArrayList<A>` is super of `ArrayList<B>`, isn't it? Can we add `B`'s and `C`'s to both `ArrayList<A>` and `ArrayList<B`>? Yes we can. Can we add `A`'s? Only to `ArrayList<A>.` But `List<? super B>` is allowed to point to `ArrayList<B>` too. So we cannot add `A`'s to `List<? super B>`.

Comment: Pretty good explanation, but `ArrayList<A>` is *not* super to `ArrayList<B>` - you must have meant that `A` is super to `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Vote up @us2012's comment.

- For `List<? super A>`

  the type is A.   A, B and C all subtype of A, so they can be added.
- For `List<? super B>`

  the type can be A, B. Both B and C are subtype of A or B.
  Think about the difference between `List<? super B> list2 = new ArrayList<A/B>()`
- For `List<? super C>`

  the type can be A, B, C. So only C is subtype of A, B or C.

For example, `Machine` -> `Car` -> `SportsCar`. for `List<? super Machine>`, no matter Machine, Car and SportsCar, they are all Machine, so it's safe to be added.

Comment: Sorry. Still not clear. eg. List<? super B>. types can be A, B. (right)
but what it means "both B and C are subtype of extend A and B"!!!

Comment: "both B and C are subtype of extend A and B" means: `List<? super B>` can be `List<A>` or `List<B>`. Both B and C can be added in `List<A>` or `List<B>`, but A not, A cannot be add in `List<B>`.

Comment: Clear now. But I only have a doubt that is why we are considering the subclasses? 'super' means 'any superclass not subclass'!!!