# Why can't one add an Object to List<? super Number>?

Tags: java, list, wildcard, type-erasure, lower-bound

Consider the following Java code:

```
List<? super Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
Number n = new Integer(1);
Object o = new Object();
list.add(n); // works, apparently Number super Number is alright
list.add(o); // compiler error!
```

But why is that the case? Since internally, type erasure makes list a list that holds Objects, why isn't it allowed to add Objects (which are superclasses of all classes, and thereby should satisfy the lower-bound wildcard) to the list?

Comment: this exact example was even used in that question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler only knows that `list` contains some supertype of `Number` (or `Number` itself), which may or may not be `Object`.  So it must disallow `Object` because it could be `List<Number>`.

Here's a [more thorough explanation](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/04/java-generics-quick-tutorial.html), scroll about half way down where it talks about "? super".

Answer (score 1):

An `Object` is not a `Number`.

A `Number` is an `Object` though.

[From the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847321/205426) of the question this is a duplicate of:

> Hence it is NOT true that you can add any supertype of Number to a
>   List; that's simply not how bounded wildcard and
>   capture conversion work. You don't declare a List
>   because you may want to add an Object to it (you can't!); you do
>   because you want to add Number objects to it (i.e. it's a "consumer"
>   of Number), and simply a List is too restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

`List<? super Number> list` defines the list you can assign it to.

In other words you can assign a `List<Number>` or a `List<Object>` to it.

Afaik `new ArrayList<>()` would be the same as `new ArrayList<Number>()`