# Is there a "superclass of" way to define a type in generics or only "extends"?

Tags: java, generics

The idea is to do something like the below and have the compiler check at compile time that toLoad is an array that can contain AType objects (ie: AType extends or is a T NOT T extends or is AType). Is there a way to do this with generics?

```
private List<AType> aList_;

<T superclassof AType> T[] loadArray(T[] toLoad) {
    for(int i = 0; i < alist_.size(); ++i) {
        toLoad[i] = (T)aList_.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Not that I know of. Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bounding generics with 'super' keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800369/bounding-generics-with-super-keyword)

Comment: This is a *general* question - the above is to simply illustrate a valid potential desire :)  That is an array may have any object assigned to it for which the array element type is a super class.  ie: The "<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)" method in java.util.List<T> is not type checked at compile time, but can throw run time exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

Changing my answer. Yes there is a "super" keyword to use with generics, but I don't think it will work here.

Here is an explanation of how it is used: [java generics super keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword)

What you should probably do is return `Collections.toArray()` on the list and bind it to the type you are using (which could be generic itself). I don't think you really need to define the return type as being a superclass of anything.

Comment: it won't compile. maybe in java 9.

Answer (score 4):

No... Java does not allow lower bounds on type variables, even though there are some valid use cases... like yours.

If you use `List`, we can use wildcard with lower bound `List<? super A>`. But not for arrays.

```
<L extends List<? super A> L load(L toLoad) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < alist_.size(); ++i) 
        toLoad.set(i, aList_.get(i) );
    return toLoad;
}
```

We can wrap an array in a List though.

```
Object[] array = new Object[length];

load(new Wrapper<>(array));

class Wrapper<E> implements List<E>
{
    E[] array;

    Wrapper(E[] array){ this.array=array; }

    E set(int index, E element)
    {
        check index<array.length
        array[index] = element;
    }
```