# Adding a typed listener to Scene's width property

Tags: generics, javafx-2, listener, scene

I want to add a listener to `Scene`'s `widthProperty` and I am wondering what I am doing wrong, here's my code:

```
ChangeListener<Double> widthListener = new ChangeListener<Double>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Double> observable, Double oldValue, Double newValue) {
        System.out.println("width changed");
    }

};        

foo.getScene().widthProperty().addListener(dimensionsListener);
```

For the line with addListener this gives me the following error:

```
The method addListener(ChangeListener<? super Number>) in the type ObservableValue<Number> is not applicable for the arguments (ChangeListener<Double>)
```

Double is a subclass of Number, so what's wrong with my code? Thanks :-)

Comment: Type of the listener, which you add must be a super type of Number: any parent of Number. Smth, more common than Number. Double is a subclass, not a superclass.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword

Answer (score 0):

why not use Number then? this works:

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
          @Override
          public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number number2) {
              System.out.println("changed");
          }
      });
```