# Difference between List<Integer> and List<? super Integer>

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between `List<Integer>` and `List<? super Integer>` .

Which one is a good practice or When we should use what ?

Comment: Does `super` work in this case?

Comment: @Marco Forberg, yes! Depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3847162/1313143

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Comment: Thanks ! I have to improve my search mechanism to find dupes ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<Integer>` is a `List` that is **bounded** to a type `Integer`. This means that it can receive and produce `Integer`.

`List<? super Integer>` is a **unbounded** `List` that accepts any value that is a `Integer` or a superclass of `Integer`.

The 2nd option is best used on the *PECS* Principle (*PECS* stands for *Producer Extends, Consumer super*). This is useful if you want to add items based on a type `T` irrespective of it's actual type.

For more information, see a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference is that you can get elements out of `List<Integer>` as type `Integer`, but when you get elements out of `List<? super Integer>`, you can only get type `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

`List<Integer>` is the best option here.

`List<? super AbstractObject>` would be better option if you are dealing with polymorphism.