# How do supertype generics in Java work?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, contravariance, supertype

I've been testing supertype generics with Java, but I've come to a roadblock. This is the sample code I was testing:

```
import java.util.*;

class GenericTests {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {      
        List<B> list3 = new ArrayList<B>();
        testMethod( list3 );
    }

    public static void testMethod( List<? super B> list ) {
        list.add( new A() );
        list.add( new B() );
    }
}

class A { }

class B extends A { }
```

When compiled, the error is:

```
GenericTests.java:20: error: no suitable method found for add(A)
            list.add( new A() );
                ^
method List.add(int,CAP#1) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method List.add(CAP#1) is not applicable
  (actual argument A cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conve
rsion)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object super: B from capture of ? super B
1 error
```

I thought that given the lower bound of B, you could add any supertype? Or does this only apply to the references (i.e. arguments within the method signature) because allowing supertypes would break the type checking?

Comment: So you though any `A` (more generic) instance could be a `B` (more specific) instance? Are you really aware of the difference between super classes and sub classes to begin with?

Comment: write private helper method for that add operation, check : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Comment: Yeah, that fact (sub as super, but not vice-versa) completely flew over my head when I was thinking about this. Now it seems much clearer.

Comment: related: [Java Generics: What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

Comment: possible duplicate of [java generics super keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration `List<? super B> list` says that `list` is a `List` of objects of some type that B inherits from.  But this type need not be compatible with `A`.  Suppose the hierarchy had been:

```
public class A {...}

public class C extends A {...}

public class B extends C {...}
```

Then, `list` could be a `List<C>`.  But then `list.add(new A())` is illegal.  An instance of `A` is not an instance of `C`. The compiler only knows that instances of `B` or a subclass can be added to `list`.

Comment: Thanks, this entirely makes sense, not sure why I thought breaking type checking and inheritance was the answer.

Comment: +1 Though there's actually no need for `C` in the example. A `List<? super B>` might be a `List<B>`, in which case adding a `new A()` shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: That's true.  I just made the possibilities obvious.  Yours is the minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

You got the idea of `? super B` differently than it actually is. What `super` do here is something like bellow:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {      
    List<B> list3 = new ArrayList<B>();
    testMethod( list3 );

    List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    testMethod(listA); --> U can pass a list of A
}

public static void testMethod( List<? super B> list ) {
    list.add( new B() );
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847321/887149) answer discuss the fact in detail.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared the discrepancies I had encountering this.