# Use of "super" with "?" in Java

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I am trying to read and understand some Java code. Here it is:

```
protected LoadTarget<? super PopulationLoadContext> createTarget(PopulationLoadContext context) {
    return createTransactionalTargetGroup(RiskScoresTables.All_Tables);
}
```

What does the `<? super PopulationLoadContext>` mean?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword

Comment: +1: for learning me something new :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, that is a [lower-bounded wildcard in generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html), which stands for `PopulationLoadContext` or any superclass of that class.

It could be a `LoadTarget<PopulationLoadContext>`, or it could be a `LoadTarget<Object>`, or anything in between (if in between classes exist).

Comment: @RichardW An excellent resource -- that I already linked.

Answer (score 1):

**What Is It?**

As stated by rgettman it's a generic type `LoadTarget` with a type argument set to a lower-bounded wildcard.

**What Does It Allow?**

At runtime a `LoadTarget` variable can be substituted (set) with a value of same type where the type argument is `PopulationLoadContext` or an ancestor.

**Why?**

To allow flexibility - a family of different instantiated types can be substituted for one another and work fine.  Within `LoadTarget`, the type parameter is used for method parameters (input) or for upper type bounds of internally instantiated generic types.  In these cases a broader type is substitutable for the original type because it is more accommodating.  The generic type is said to have contravariance with it's type parameter

Answer (score 1):

More generally (not just Java speaking), if you want to get a bigger picture, it is also called **covariance / contravariance**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29 see Java section:

"given a `List<? extends Foo>`, then an element can be retrieved and safely assigned to a `Foo` type (**covariance**). Given a `List<? super Foo>`, then a `Foo` object can be safely added as an element (**contravariance**)."