# Why adding an element (of correct type) into a List through a method of <?> is a compilation error?

Tags: java, generics

I have few doubts regarding generics wildcard concepts.

1.Let say i have a method: `void write(List<?> list)` and i call this with a `List<Dog> list`,`write(list)` and trying to add in write() like `list.add(new Dog())` is a compilation error, why?

My understanding is  mean an unknown type and can accept any type, so if i call with a type Dog then it should allow to add into the list a Dog... What i infer wrong here?

2.Now, if i use bounded wild cards, `write(List<? super Dog> list>` it solves the above problem, why? and this allows me to add an Dog to the list But as per understanding about ?super Dog... it should allow Dog and super's of Dog.... so i should be able to add an Animal also to the list? But getting an compilation error.

I think this problem is because `write(List<? super Dog> list>` allows only me to call write() with a list of either or super's of Dog and once you called it with a type... you can only add to the list that type only,   Am I correct?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let say i have a method: void write(List list) and i call this with
>   a List list,write(list) and trying to add in write() like
>   list.add(new Dog()) is a compilation error, why?

`?` is a wildcard operator in generics, now what it means is that you ***don't exactly know*** what kind of `List` you are getting. So how can you be sure that it can be a `List` of `Dog`s. If it was a `List<Cat>` then your `write` method would have added a `Dog` to it. So Java restricts you from doing that.

> Now, if i use bounded wild cards, write(List list> it
>   solves the above problem, why?

`? super Dog` stands for any super class of Dog including itself. So when you get a `List<? super Dog>` in `write` you know that the List is a list of either `List<Object> or List<Dog>`. In both cases it is safe to add a new `Dog` to the list.

Comment: I have tried to answer your questions. Have a look.

Comment: I still have a doubt!  If i call write(list), List<Object> list, Then why i am failing to add an Object, it only allow me to add a Dog?

Comment: Assuming `Dog extends Animal`. Again because you can't be sure that the `List` being passed is a `List<Object>` it may even be a `List<Animal>` and it is not valid to add a `Object` to a `List<Animal>`. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword for more on this. It gives a very detailed example for it.

Comment: I am passing List<Object> to write(), so i am sure it's a list of Object. Then it should be legal to add an Object in list. Why declaring ? super Dog allows only to add a Dog only?

Comment: Compiler wont ask you what you are going to pass, semantics are fixed and don't work according to the code you write. Imagine write() method being public and some other person calls it with a `List<Animal>`.

Comment: Also try to read the link I have provided. There are very great explanations on that post.