# Generics subtle differences

Tags: java

```
  class P {

   }
  class Q extends P {

   }
  class R extends Q { 

   }
  class S extends R {

  }

  public class Manager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      X<? super R> x4 = null;
      x4.test(new S());
      x4.test(new R());
      x4.test(new P());//compile time error

     }
}

    class X<A> {
      void test(A obj) {

       }
    }
```

//means that R or superclass of R i.e P, Q or Object but then why I get a compile time error on line as specified in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass objects extending R, i.e. R or S, but not parents of it.
R is the super class of any passed instance!

Answer (score 4):

Here are some rules from the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)

> A type argument `T1` is said to contain another type argument `T2`,
>   written `T2 <= T1`, if the set of types denoted by `T2` is provably a
>   subset of the set of types denoted by `T1` under the reflexive and
>   transitive closure of the following rules (where `<:` denotes subtyping
>   (§4.10)):
>
> `? super T <= ? super S if S <: T`
>
> `? super T <= ?`
>
> `? super T <= ? extends Object`
>
> `T <= ? super T`

The notation

```
X<? super R> x4 = null;
```

declares `X` with a generic wildcard type argument that has a lower bound of `R`.

With the rules above and your declaration of the variable,  we can determine that the wildcard covers any sub types of `R` and `R` itself. `S` is a sub type of `R`, `R` is `R`, `P` is not a sub type of `R`.

The confusion may come in the following. You can do

```
X<? super R> x4 = new X<P>();
```

since `P` is a superclass of `R`. However, when you want to use the type parameter of the class `X`, all you know is that it must at least be an `R`.

Further reading:

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)
- [Lower Bounded Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html)
- [java generics super keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword)