# Extending a class in the method signature

Tags: java

Can someone explain what this does? This is a generics question but since I'm learning in Java I tagged it as Java.

`public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void quickSort(T[] list) {...}`

What I don't understand is this part: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

I have tried looking at [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/231251-public-static-t-extends-javalangcomparable-super-t-void-quickso/) but it doesn't seem to explain it in a clear way.

My guess is: the genetic type T extends the Comparable interface which itself requires a generic type to be a superclass of a generic type. But I don't really understand this.

Comment: You could start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. Well I do understand the ? and somewhat <? extends T> and <? super T> though I'm only going through this concept briefly as part of a course curriculum so I think it's going to take too much time, so if there are some really helpful examples as a starter it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
public class X implements Comparable<X> {
}
```

The class `X` implements `Comparable` which satisfies `extends Comparable` and the generic parameter of `Comparable` is `X` because `X` is `super` `X` ([java generics super keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword))

Another example:

```
public class Y {}

public class X extends Y implements Comparable<Y> {
}
```

Another example:

```
public class X implements Comparable<Object> {
}
```

But this won't work:

```
public class A {}

public class X implements Comparable<A> {
}
```

As the class `X` is only comparable to objects that are not in it's inheritance hierarchy.

The sorting algorithm is just going to call `x.compareTo(y)` and it needs to know at compile time that that is valid.