# about generics strange behavior for me

Tags: java, generics

take the following code:

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List<? super Integer> list2 = list1;
        list2.add(1);
        list1.add("two");
        //list2.add("three"); // will never compile!!.
        System.out.println("list1:  " + list1.toString());
        System.out.println("list2:  " + list2.toString());

    }

}
```

here is the output:

```
list1:  [1, two]
list2:  [1, two]
```

on the one hand, list2 doesn't allow the add() method on objects like the String "three"; but on the other hand it references a List containing Objects.

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual question is? I'm assuming it's something like "How can list2 appear to contain a string (in the print statement) when its type is `? super Integer`, especially given that adding a string to it as `list2.add("three")` won't compile?" but all you've really given is an observation.

Comment: What you have is a list of valid assignments that may look strange if you don't think about the sequence it is processed in. At the point of you assigning `list2 = list1;` it is perfectly valid, even at a later point you can add new entry (to both lists as they are in fact one single list) by `list1.add("three");` There is nothing strange and unusual about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't care what kind of objects the list *instance* accepts. At byte code level any reference is accepted because of type erasure. It just knows about two variables with a `List` type parameterized with a particular generic type. That one of these variables is assignable to the other is something that is checked and then forgotten.

So when you try to add `"three"` it looks at the generic type that is accepted by the type of `list2`, sees it doesn't match, and throws a compile error.

As for the program: there isn't any problem. If you want to restrict the objects you want to add or remove from the list through a variable reference then that is up to you.

Note that it is impossible to retrieve a `String` from the list referenced by the variables  without a cast.

Comment: I agree thought that this kind of thing is *far* from intuitive and I'm not a big fan of the current setup with regards to generics.

Comment: Could you explain why `list2.add(new Object());` does not compile, as `Object` is clearly a super type of `Integer`? Shouldn't you be able to _add_ any super type, but only _get_ an `Integer` without casting?

Comment: I can only explain this through a [reference to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3847162/589259). It's kind of the same, but without the assignment from `list1` to `list2`. As said, this is not intuitive to me either.

Comment: Yea, this is rather unintuitive. For me, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/905488) helped to clarify the problem better. In short, you cannot make the list addition I suggested, because `list2` could have a run-time type of `ArrayList<Integer>`. My assumption was backwards; you can only _add_ sub-types of the parameterized type (or the type itself), and you can only _get_ `Object`s, when using lower bounded wildcards. Producer Extends, Consumer Super (PECS): a list of type `List<? super Integer>` can only _consume_ `Integer`s (and sub-types of `Integer`s).

Comment: `List<? super Integer>` refers to a list that accepts some _unknown but specific_ supertype of `Integer`.  For example, `List<? super Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()` compiles, and that list cannot accept anything but `Integer`.

Comment: A source of confusion (probably for the OP as well) is that `List<? super Integer> list = new ArrayList<Object>()` also compiles, but you cannot `add` anything but `Integer`s to that list either because of the way it has been declared with the lower bounded wildcard. So I think it's misleading to say that the list can "accept" any supertypes of `Integer`s, because it can only consume objects having a type whose upper bound is `Integer`. The types of objects "accepted" from a read/write context are different (as pointed out in the linked answer).

Comment: @LouisWasserman Although my answer I think is correct I would be very happy to upvote a better one from you - feel free to update as well.