# Java Generic method with super keyword

Tags: java, generics

I'm practicing Java now and trying to dive into generics. I want to make this code work:

```
public class TwoD { // simple class to keep two coordinate points
    int x, y;

    TwoD(int a, int b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
}

public class ThreeD extends TwoD { //another simple class to extend TwoD and add one more point
    int z;

    ThreeD(int a, int b, int c) {
        super(a, b);
        z = c;
    }
}
public class FourD extends ThreeD { //just like previous
    int t;

    FourD(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        super(a, b, c);
        t = d;
    }
}
public class Coords<T extends TwoD> { //class to keep arrays of objects of any previous class
    T[] coords;

    Coords(T[] o) {
        coords = o;
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a method which will be using objects of TwoD and ThreeD but not FourD.
I've tried that:

```
static void showXYZsub(Coords<? super FourD> c) {
        System.out.println("X   Y   Z:");
        for (int i = 0; i < c.coords.length; i++)
            System.out.println(c.coords[i].x + "    " + c.coords[i].y + 
                    "   " + c.coords[i].z);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

but I got an error "z cannot be resolved or is not a field".

As far I know, keyword `super` should filter object of any class which extending `FourD`, and `FourD` itself, but even if I'd change `FourD` to `ThreeD` or `TwoD`, the error will be the same.

I.e. if I use `super` only TwoD fields are visible, but in case of `extends` everything works fine.
Is `Coords` class have problem or what? Please help.

And sorry for engrish.

---edit: calling for showXYZsub

```
FourD fd[] = { 
new FourD(1, 2, 3, 4), new FourD(6, 8, 14, 8), new FourD(22, 9, 4, 9),
        new FourD(3, -2, -23, 17) };
Coords<FourD> fdlocs = new Coords<FourD>(fd);
showXYZsub(fdlocs);
```

Comment: Can you add the calling showXYZsub method part as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Coords<? super FourD> c
```

This means: `c` is a `Coords` where the type argument is some unknown type that is a supertype of `FourD`.

The member variable `z` was defined in `ThreeD`, which is a supertype of `FourD`. However, `? super FourD` does not guarantee that the type `T` is at least a `ThreeD`. It could for example also be `TwoD` or `Object`, which are also supertypes of `FourD`.

So, you cannot access the member variable `z`, because the type `T` might not have this member variable.

It looks that you actually wanted to use:

```
Coords<? extends ThreeD> c
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible, because how are you going to get `point.z` when the argument is a TwoD point?

You said

```
be using objects of TwoD and ThreeD but not FourD
```

Why are you restricting `FourD` objects?
By inheritance, every `FourD` **is** a `ThreeD`. So if something takes ThreeD, it should also be able to handle `FourD`s.

Note that it makes sense: if your function takes three dimensional points, it won't be able to handle 2D, because it will lack a dimension, but will take 4Ds with no problem, just ignoring the extra one.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `Coords<? super FourD>` it means to Java `Allow every class which is a super class of FourD and it means TwoD and ThreeD are allowed`. Actualy it means one of the class of this family. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword) for more.

Now both of these classe have `x` and `y` parameters so it means whatever allowed class we get we are safe with printing them (`x` and `y`). But when you include `z` it has no presence in class `TwoD` so if you pass an object of this the program will fail. So Java takes a defensive approach and does not allow you.

What exactly you want is probably allow `ThreeD` and `FourD`. Now class `FourD` extends `ThreeD` so the relation `Coords<? extends ThreeD>` should work fine becuase it means `Allow ThreeD or any one who extends ThreeD (read FourD)` which is what we want`. S that is the solution in that case.

**References:**
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html