# Usage of super in method declaration

Tags: java, generics, methods, super

I would like to understand what this Java declaration is doing:

```
public static <AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> int mymethod( AnyType x ) {
    /* ... */
}
```

From my basic knowledage of Java, I think all it's doing is telling you that the param x must be of any type, but that type must extend Comparable?

Comment: No. it means that the type must be a subtype of AnyType.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java generics super keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword)

Comment: Please do some prior research next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. This method indicates that it takes an argument of a type that extends a `Comparable` (Note that I would have called the type parameter `T` instead of `AnyType` for readability).

Now for the `super` in `Comparable<? super AnyType>>`, it means that this comparable implementation can actually be, for example, an implementation of `Comparable<Object>`, that is a comparable type that can be compared to an object. *More generally, the type accepted by the method can be a `Comparable` which can be compared to some type that is a **superclass or superinterface** of it*, hence the keyword `super`. In other words, the method can be invoked as follows:

```
// An object of this type can be compared to an Object
class X implements Comparable<Object> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        ...
    }


}

X x = new X();
mymethod(x);
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally understood it perfectly ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic method, i.e. its type parametrization is not related to the class' parametrization if any.

The `<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>` part is the generic parametrization of the method.

The `extends` keyword should not be confused with the `extends` keyword when declaring a class: in this case it looks more like "is assignable from", in other words, **IS-A**.

`Comparable<T>` is an interface - see docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Your method parametrization will make it so that your method accepts any parameter, as long as its type implements `Comparable`.

Specifically, it needs to be a `Comparable` of itself or any super-type (that's what the `super` part means, as opposed to `extends`).

For instance, you can pass a `String` argument because `String` implements `Comparable<String>` (amongst others).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, parameter must be a sub-type of Comparable.